# How to load form filter module only on certain node type in Drupal admin?

Tags: drupal, drupal-forms

I would like to load form filter module in drupal admin only on certain node types.

My goal is to exclude form filtering from profile content type (because it is in conflict with Content profile module).

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as the node form alteration is hard-coded in the module. Here is an issue related to this - http://drupal.org/node/332073. However, if you are not averse to editing the module, then you can achieve it. The code is in hook_form_alter of formfilter_ui module.